# Why is the binomial coefficient $C(-1,k)=(-1)^k$?

Tags: combinatorics, binomial-coefficients

It is known that $$C(n,k) = \frac{n^{k<}}{k!},$$ where $C(n,k)$ is the notation for the binomial coefficient and $k<$ is notation for '$k$ lower' which gives
$$n(n-1)(n-2)....(n-k+1).$$ For $n = -1$ it is the case that $C(-1,k) = (-1)^k$.  However, by definition this should equal $(-1)^{k<}/k!$.  I can't seem to figure out why though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They're the same thing:
$$C(-1,k)=\frac{(-1)(-2)\cdots(-k)}{1\cdot 2\cdots k}=(-1)^k$$

Comment: Well I feel silly now, thank you very much for clarifying.

Answer (score 2):

(I prefer the notation $x^{\underline k}$ for the falling factorial that you write $x^{<k}$.)

$$\binom{-1}k=\frac{(-1)^{\underline k}}{k!}=\frac{(-1)(-2)(-3)\dots(-k)}{(1)(2)(3)\dots(k)}=\frac{(-1)^kk!}{k!}=(-1)^k\;.$$